# How to formulate the whole number part of decimal number in equation

Tags: rational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I would like to formulate the classification with equal interval method.

I know how to formulate the interval:

$$
\frac{(Highest\;Value - Lowest\;Value)}{Number\;of\;Classes}=Interval\;Value
$$

But how to assign a value to its class? 
For example:
Value is 75 and Interval is 20.
$$
\frac{75}{20} = 3.5 
$$

The class of value 75 is 3.

But I don't know how to formulize the whole number part of decimal number?

$$
\frac{Value}{Interval} = 3.5 ??
$$

Comment: Try $1+\lfloor\frac{Value - Lowest Value}{Interval Value}\rfloor$

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Can you explain it with an example, please?

Comment: For example, lowest value is 20, highest value is 90, number of classes is 10, then interval is (90-20)/10=7. If value is from 20 to 27 it is in first class, if value is from 27 to 34 it is in second class. To find class for arbitrary value, you should subtract lowest value and divide result by interval. After that you should do ceiling of result to make it positive integer. For example, value is 53. (53-20)/7=4+5/7. After ceiling it becomes 5, so this value must be placed in fifth class.